# Bootstrap: centering a Hero unit horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Hero unit that contains a Django form. How do I center it on the page, both horizontally and vertically?

EDIT:

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 hero-unit">

            {{ form }}

        </div>
    </div>
```

That's pretty much what the form looks like.

Comment: Please post the code as well. Generally its a good idea to post a question with maximum information . Please read the guidelines on How to post a question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFiddle with form](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/YmmVS/)

**Edit** : Just wanted to improve this answer for anyone who needs help .

Well This is how you can implement a Hero-unit with form centered in middle .

First the css :

```
.hero-unit {
padding:50px 50px 50px 50px;
    }
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    width: 61px;
    }
.form-horizontal .controls {
margin-left: 80px;
    }
/* Landscape phones and down */
  @media (max-width: 480px) { 

 .hero-unit{
margin-left:-20px;
margin-right:-20px;
  }
 .form-horizontal .controls {
margin-left: 0;
  }
   }
```

The Html Part :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="offset4 span4">
            <legend>Sign in to WebApp</legend>
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like changing the padding percentage also works.